# Javascript causing html elments to disappear on android chrome

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, shopify

I think people who have experienced such things can help me. I will try to be as much detailed as possible. I have been trying to find the bug in my code but later found out that it just doesn't work on android chrome. I am building my website on Shopify. It works on firefox and chrome desktop as well as in devtools to check the website view on mobile screens. The problem is that a call back to a synchronous function (say f1) inside an async function (say f2) is causing the content on webpage to disappear. And these content don't have any position property defined in them in the CSS. The content with any position property defined are not disappearing but if their children don't have any position property defined on them, they disappear as well. The content is visible when

1. I remove the f1 from f2.
2. I click on any input field (which are invisible as well) to focus in on them
3. I click on a button (which is invisible) with an event listener which is inside a parent with position property defined

Buttons with position property not defined (even not on their parents) don't work unless they are made visible by using above methods.

```
async function generateCart() {
  try {
    var data = await GET();
    for(let i = data.items.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var item = data.items[i];
        var prod = {
          'name': item.product_title,
          'handle' : item.handle,
          'image_url' : item.featured_image.url,
          'id': item.variant_id,
          'price': (item.price/100),
          'comp_price': (item.properties.comp_price)
        };
        addLineItem(prod, item.quantity);
    }
  } catch(error) {
    alert(error.message + ". Unable to generate cart.");
    await updateCart(null, 0, "CLEAR");
  } finally {
    if(cartItems.size != 0) emptyBag.classList.add('hide');
    cartDrawer.classList.remove('hide');
    cartBtn.classList.remove('hide');
  }
}

generateCart();
```

When I remove the addLineItem() function from the generateCart() function. Everything works fine.
If there are no elements in the data array, the code works fine because the addLineItem() is not run in that case.

The addLineItem() creates a new table row and adds it in a table.

Comment: It would be very good if you provide some code :)

Comment: @capchuck Added the code